# Blend shadow casted by a 3d object over an object in real-life footage (VFX)

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I blend my character (to the right) into the scene. I want some shadow casted by the character over the doll (real-life). How do I do it in CYCLES?
[image]

Comment: You will need to recreate the doll in 3D just to cast the shadow and use the same technic explained by @parameciostudio

Comment: I did that in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZQKn0THf8s go the the tornado scene and check the shadow. It isn't a good example since the quality is bad (it's a hobby for me) but the technic is the one posted in the answer adding a cilinder for the straw roll. If the answer is not expanded I will post my straw roll and the technic when I get home.

Comment: Sorry but what's the technique you mentioned?

Comment: Not me, @parameciostudio. You need to set that object to only receive shadows and not render any material on it, I don't remember where you select that (check object properties), have to get home to open my old blend files. If no one can answer before I will tell you how it is done when I get home.

Comment: Check this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6796/how-to-render-a-shadow-without-the-object-in-the-scene

Comment: Oldie but goodie http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/518/how-to-make-a-model-cast-shadows-onto-the-world-texture-background/519#519

Comment: @YoMismo It works casting shadows, but how can an object receive shadows without casting (the real object already casts the own shadow)? It is quite easy with Blender Internal, but I didn't find a quick solution with Cycles yet.

Comment: Have you tried @parameciostudio answer? Looks like that is the way, you can also check the next blenderartist thread http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?251177-Cycles-how-to-get-a-plane-to-recieve-shadow-while-invisible&highlight=cycles+shadow+catcher I haven't done it with cycles

Answer (score 1):

As for the floor, you should add a transparent object receiving shadows.

Since Cycles has been thought for photo-realistic renders, there's no easy way to isolate shadows.

You can use *Layer* and *Render Passes*.

### Foreground

This layer contains all you want to render (your character)

[image]

### Transparent objects receiveing shadows

This layer contains the helper objects that will receive shadows (the puppet).

Since we won't use any color informations, we'll use the *Diffuse Direct Pass*.

[image]

### Background

This layer contains the shadow of our hero.

To avoid the "helper object" to cast any shadow, we'll exclude its layer.

[image]

### Background image

[image]

### Scene

[image]

### Composite

[image]

Use the *RGB Curve Nodes* to adjust the shadows and to set the white level (white is transparent in *Multiply Node*)

Comment: I think it would be helpful to add details as to *how* they might do this.

Comment: So... what about the doll? And it'll be nice if you show me a more detailed answer.

Comment: just tried to give the floor a Transparent shader but It didnt help

Comment: Hey @RayMairlot, If you are the same Ray Mairlot that has youtube tutorials on Blender I would like to thank you for that. They are great and the main title of the video (see comments to the question) have been done using your technique. I also thank you in the credits (hope you don't mind).

Answer (score 1):

Ok since the other answer hasn't been expanded, here goes my explanation.

I did this with Blender Render, but in the link I posted as a comment to your question goes the explanation for cycles. Regarding the doll receiving the shadow of your character...

As you can see in the next image, I have setup a ground and a straw roll that matches the background (sorry, I lost the background image but I used it as reference to place both ground and straw roll).

[image: Image setup & material]

As you can see, for the straw object a material is created, in the material you can see what I have selected in the shadow section (receive, receive transparent and shadows only). The rest of the material sections/options should be unchecked.

The next image shows a render, as you can see neither the ground nor the straw roll can be seen, just the shadows the tornado creates.

[image: Render with only shadows]

And the final composite

[image: Final composite]