# Create "Floor" plane in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine

I've got a scene that I've motion tracked and it seems to be working well. Then I used "Setup tracking scene" to create a cube layer, then a floor layer that would only exist to act as a shadow catcher.
[image]
When I render this in Blender Render, such as Blender Guru does in his tutorial video, it looks fine.
[image]
However, because of what I would like to do with this scene in the future, I would rather use cycles instead of blender render. However, I don't think the nodes are set up right or something because when I render it in Cycles, the floor layer still appears.
[image]
I would like the floor layer to only act as a shadow catcher AND (this is hard to describe) a layer where anything behind it would not be rendered. So like if I had a cube that stuck through the floor layer, only the part that is in front of it would be shown.
I should also note that I have no experience with nodes, so that's probably the problem.

Comment: As long [this feature](https://developer.blender.org/D1788) is in development, you can find a nice workaround [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19765/cycles-shadeless-shadow-catcher-material-for-rendering-onto-footage).

Comment: @poor I forgot to mention that I would like the shadow catcher layer to not render in the final result, but it's shadows will. Will this method provide that?

Comment: What poor means is there is currently no one-step solution to do what you want. You have to set up a mix of material nodes and compositing solution

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47569/render-shadows-over-a-transparent-background-in-cycles/47989#47989

Answer (score 1):

This feature is now included.

Select the shadowcatcher object, go to the object properties and check **Shadow Catcher** under *Cycles Settings*.

It will render a shadow but mask the object behind it.

[image: shadowcatcher]