# Shadow Catcher in cycles problem

Tags: node-editor, shadows

I've [asked around](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64301/create-floor-plane-in-cycles?) and people have told me that [this tutorial](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19765/cycles-shadeless-shadow-catcher-material-for-rendering-onto-footage) should allow me to do what I want to do. I've followed the steps outlined, however I am not getting the result I want.

My first layer looks like this:
[image]
The cubic object is what I want to be shown in the render.

My second layer looks like this:
[image]
The floor panel is meant to catch shadows, and should not be displayed in the final render. If the cube and the floor were on the same layer, the cube would be intercepting the floor, like this:
[image]

Meaning the shadow should be cast like this:
[image]
Except the floor layer should not be rendered, but the shadow cast onto the floor layer should be rendered.

Here's how I set up my nodes (Exactly as in the tutorial provided above)
[image]
And here's my render layers (Exactly as in the tutorial)

[image]

However, my finished product looks like this:
[image]
I want the shadow of the cube to catch onto the screen.
I have no prior experience with nodes, so that's probably where I went wrong.

Comment: The tutorial has BG Clean in the top render slot and BG with shadows under it - which would be Only Catcher in your case - so not exactly like the tutorial...

Comment: @Patdog I guess I overlooked that. Nonetheless, I figured out the problem. It was as simple as Shift-clicking both layers down in the layer switcher then rendering. They both have to be selected for it to render both layers.