# Blender Cycles Shadow Over Transparent Background Using Emission Objects

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, compositing-nodes

I'm trying to render an object with a shadow onto a transparent background and have tried using the compositor to overlay the 'shadow layer' (ignoring the white background) with the 'object layer'.

I have managed to do this is using 'Sun lamps' but I would prefer to use Emission planes. This doesn't seem to have the same effect for some reason, can someone please help with a node setup for emission lighting please? I'd rather not duplicate objects onto other layers if possible as I am animating them for sprite sheets.

My current setup is as  below:

[image]

Thanks,

Luke

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47569/render-shadows-over-a-transparent-background-in-cycles/47989#47989