# Background photo missing in render

Tags: rendering, image

I made a campfire in Blender and I would like to render it with a specific photo in the background, but when I start rendering, the photo is missing.

[image: Screenshot]

Edit:

Thanks for your links they explain my problem. But I have a node setup like this:

[image: Node setup]

I don't know where to link the image and alpha node! Is there a possibility to create a new node channel where I can set my complete campfire nodes as one node?

Comment: Background images are viewport only. For rendering see: [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/85100/cant-get-background-image-to-show-in-cycles-render/85111) and [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40648/cycles-not-rendering-with-background-image/67925)

Comment: Images for background aren't added into material nodes (unless you create a plane specifically for that image behind your objects and assign new material with that image, but even then you won't insert the image into cube material), images for background are often added with compositing nodes

Comment: ok i understand. But i cant get the necessary nodes into my node setup. Is there any possibility to load all the nodes from the campfie into one node? Than i can create the node setup out of the other links from post 1 and 2. But actually i dont know how to do this