# I don't know how to add shadows to hide maps

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, lighting

[image]I have a spider and an hdri map. the spider is catching reflections but not making shadows on the ground. please help.

Comment: HDR Environment maps don't generally cast very hard shadows because of their soft uniform lighting

Comment: could you please upload your blend-file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and/or provide a screenshot of your render-szene? it's hard to help without further information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render shadows over a transparent background in cycles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47569/render-shadows-over-a-transparent-background-in-cycles)

Comment: The problem is that the HDRi is "surrounding" your scene (Like it's covering the inside of a sphere). You spider isn't actually standing on anything to cast a shadow on. Here's a tutorial that isn't the same Situation because it is using a photograph. But around beginning around 2.0 minutes there is useful information for you. https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/render-onto-photo-background