# Remove plane while keeping shadows intact

Tags: shadows, layers, motion-capture

I have watched BlenderGuru's camera tracking tutorial and tried to do the same with cycles but i want to remove the base plane which is used for shadows while keep the shadows intact. How can I do it?

[BlenderGuru Camera tracking using blender render](https://youtu.be/CVPcT0dJmoY)

[image: my image]

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47569/render-shadows-over-a-transparent-background-in-cycles/47989#47989

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the plane in object mode, in the properties menu, go to the object subfolder, open up cycles settings and check the shadow catcher box. The plane will now act as a shadow canvas, and i actually suggest making it a bit bigger so that it catches all of the skull's shadow.